# How hard is it to transfer everything from an iPhone?

Tags: data-transfer

My wife has an iPhone 4. She's due for something new, and I want her to get an Android just so we have the same OS.

She's concerned about losing contacts and her iTunes music. How hard is it to move these to a new Android?

Answer (score 2):

Music can be easily copied. Just open the folder where you keep the music on your hard drive and just copy & paste it on your Android device.

For contacts and calender, check [this](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/138740?rd=1) Google Help article (screenshot below):

[image: Steps to set up Google Sync with your iOS device]

Answer (score 0):

For contacts, use a PC and [transfer the iPhone address book to the Android](http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-transfer-contacts-from-iphone-to-android/). For text messages, back up the iPhone with iTunes. Then use the iOS backup file for the SMS messages and import it to your SD card on the Android phone. Next, download iSMS2droid freebe app from Google Play and locate the iPhone SMS database file from within the app.